# What is the proper data format to pass while rendering template in Backbone.js. JSON or Model?

Tags: backbone.js

To make it simple, should I do

```
$(@el).html @template(model: @model)
```

or

```
$(@el).html @template(@model.toJSON())
```

I used to go the first way, that's what I was taught. But recently I found second way is acceptable too. It at least saved a lot @model.get("attribute_name") while rendering templates.

So what's the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `@model.toJSON()` is better, for the reason you've mentioned: it makes for cleaner templates.

This:

```
<div><%= name %></div>
```

Is easier on the eyes than:

```
<div><%= this.model.get("name") %></div>
```

Look at some of the [example apps](http://backbonejs.org/examples/todos/todos.js) on Backbone.js, you'll see they use the `.toJSON()` approach.

---

<sub>I suppose it's also a question of whether you want your templates to have access to the full View object.  Obviously, that is not possible once you use `toJSON()`.  To me, not having that access is a plus respecting the separation of concerns, since the template should be about presentation, with minimal code, and appearing as close to regular HTML markup as possible.</sub>

Comment: I was convinced. Thank you sir.